# How can I use Neo4js algorithm plugin to calculate Jaccard on list of strings?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph contains the labels `X` and `UnknownX` which are linked by the relationship `:MAYBE` and I'd like to identify which is the proper `X` if `match (u:UnknownX {name: 'John Doe'})-[r:MAYBE]-() return count(r) > 1`. For this I figured Jaccard might be a decent initial approach.

The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/similarity-jaccard/) of the Jaccard similarity implementation of Neo4j's algorithm plugin states that

```
The Jaccard similarity function computes the similarity of two lists of numbers.
```

I'd like to use the implementation to calculate the similarity of lists of string values. Is there a way Neo4j could calculate the similarity on some kind of integer representation of my strings?

Example queries:

```
RETURN algo.similarity.jaccard([1,2,3], [1,2,4,5]) AS similarity // 0.4
RETURN algo.similarity.jaccard(['hello', 'world'], ['hello', 'world', '!']) // throws error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting each string into an array of character codes (based on some encoding, like UTF-8 or UTF-16).

For example, to compare 'hello' and 'hello!' using UTF-8 encoding, this query:

```
RETURN algo.similarity.jaccard(
  apoc.text.bytes('hello'),
  apoc.text.bytes('hello!')
)
```

would return `0.5714285714285714`.

The [apoc.text.bytes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_overview_text_functions) function returns a list of character codes according to some character encoding (using UTF-8 by default).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately this seems to break Jaccard, seeing as `RETURN algo.similarity.jaccard(
  apoc.text.bytes('hello'),
  apoc.text.bytes('hello')
)` should return `1` but instead returns `2/3`.

Comment: So I looked at `apoc.text.bytes('hello')` which deterministically returns `[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]`. Then I fed that directly into `jaccard()` and saw that the result is `2/3`. I guess I will use `apoc.text.bytes()` or something similar to generate numerical hash values of my strings and at the same time ask the devs of `jaccard` what's happening.